# Driving a borrowed Car in the USA as a German Citizen

Tags: usa, driving, road-trips, driving-licenses, california

A friend of mine and I are planning a visit to the USA this July, where my parents now live. We are planning on making a road trip through parts of the USA (mainly California, but also Nevada and possibly Arizona). My father has agreed to lend us a car to use for this road trip.

Both my friend and I are German citizens and we are both in possession of standard German driving licences. I am 22 and he is 21.

My question is it legal for us to use this car and are there any special prerequisites we need to fulfill in order to be able to use this car?

Comment: There is no issue with you having possession of the car provided father has given consent and you have all the paperwork.  But, what father needs to do is *contact his insurance company* to find our if your trip is considered non-regular use.  Non-regular use is covered by the owner's policy in most cases.  A few days shouldn't be a problem but it's good to understand that before it makes a difference.

Comment: You need to carry a copy of the proof-of-insurance in the car at all times, and since you're not the policyholder, it wouldn't hurt to also have a letter from the policyholder *"I am lending my car to X and Y between <Dates> and that is covered by my insurance"*. (Assuming of course as @Johns-305 mentions that you are covered. If not, you'll have to either have him ask his company what coverage he has to add for you, or buy your own policy.)